# Mapbox opengl line with different colors based on metadata like speed and other information (eg leaning angle, acceleration)

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm working on a map on whitch I want to draw the path I drove with my motorcycle. For this I want to use mapbox opengl because of the wonderful graphical features. I have dificulties to understand the different kind of sources that Mapbox offers (https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/sources/). I collect the data with my self developed logger (lat, lng, speed, acc, gyro, leaning angle, alt) and can export them in any kind of file or format. But as far as I understood, geo.json files are not able to support metadata. So I looked up the "Tiled Sources" but here I getting into trouble. Do I need a mapper from Mapbox from my file and then consume the data to mapbox or do i have a direct options to import my CSV and define the data columns.

Answer (score -1):

> But as far as I understood, geo.json files are not able to support metadata.

Incorrect. You can store any metadata you like either on the `properties` attribute of a `Feature`, or at the top level of a `FeatureCollection`.

> So I looked up the "Tiled Sources" but here I getting into trouble.

You don't want a tiled source.

> Do I need a mapper from Mapbox from my file and then consume the data to mapbox or do i have a direct options to import my CSV and define the data columns.

Probably what you want is to convert the CSV to GeoJSON. You can even do it dynamically in your code front end.

After loading the CSV (using something like D3's `csv` method), you can do something like this:

```
const geojson = {
            type: 'FeatureCollection',
            features: rows.map((row, id) => ({
                type: 'Feature',
                geometry: {
                    type: 'Point',
                    coordinates: [+row.longitude], +row.latitude],
                },
                properties: {
                    id,
                    ...row
                }
            }))
        }

map.addSource('mysource', { type: 'geojson', data: geojson });
```

Comment: Thank you to the answer! dies this work for "type":"LineString" too?

Comment: If you had some way of storing LineString coordinates within a CSV, you could make that work.